# Inserting date automatically when a tick box is ticked

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp, data-validation

I have a simple sheet that has two columns with tick boxes in them (columns 5 and 8) The goal is when the box is ticked the date and time are inserted in the column next to it.  I have got it working correctly with one column with the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
  if(col == 5) {
    var adjacentCell = aCell.offset(0, 1);  
    var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm:ss");
    adjacentCell.setValue(newDate);
  }
}
```

For the life of me, I can't work out how to modify that so that it works with column 8 as well.  Any help will save me tearing my hair out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can simply just double it:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
      nextCell.setValue(newDate);
    }
    if( r.getColumn() == 8 ) { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      var newDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
      nextCell.setValue(newDate1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the reply.  I had actually tried that and what it does is ignore the first part and only works on column 8.  Clicking column 5 does nothing.

Comment: @ceolnamara try now what it does

Comment: good morning, thank you for taking the time to look at this.  I tried the amended code and this has stopped putting the date in any of the adjacent columns :(

Comment: @ceolnamara answer updated (and tested)

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I just had to change the sheet name as i was using custom ones and your script run as it should.